# Is there a Foursquare connect button for Titanium Mobile apps?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, foursquare, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Titanium's KitchenSink samples feature an official Facebook connect button, but Foursquare connection asks for username and password instead of using oAuth.
Is there an official Foursquare button or ready-to-use oauth library/module for Titanium mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official foursquare button/library for Titanium. Foursquare uses OAuth2 and has example code for Android/iOS/Blackberry available on the developer website: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client